# Load content into game after game has already started?

Tags: c#, monogame

I want to load content into my game after the game has already started when a new object is created.

Basically, I have this code.

```
public class RenderObject
{
    public Texture2D image;
    public string graphic;
    public float angle;
    public Vector2 location;
    public float alpha = 1.0f;

    public static List<RenderObject> renderObjects = new List<RenderObject>();
    int _x;
    int _y;

    public RenderObject(int _x, int _y,string _graphic)
    {
        location = new Vector2(_x, _y);
        graphic = _graphic;
        renderObjects.Add(this);
    }

    public RenderObject(int _x, int _y)
    {
        this._x = _x;
        this._y = _y;
    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        image = content.Load<Texture2D>(graphic);
    }
```

I have a LoadContent function and when it's used in the regular LoadContent it works perfectly..

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        for (int i = 0; i < RenderObject.renderObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            RenderObject.renderObjects[i].LoadContent(this.Content);
        }





        //TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here 
    }
```

except obviously this wouldn't be called when a new object is created. Whenever a new object would be created it would crash because the texture of itself would return null because it isn't loaded. The solution I had was to make a static Texture2D that was loaded during LoadContent but it seems really unintuitive to have a huge LoadContent that loads every single asset in the game, all coded manually.

Comment: What's wrong with a single huge LoadContent?

Comment: Seems really ridiculous to not be able to have it be based per class or something similar, and it would be ridiculously hard to keep track of all the things loaded or not loaded.

Comment: Load everything => you do not have to keep track of all things.

Answer (score 0):

> except obviously this wouldn't be called when a new object is created

Is there any specific reason why you can't call LoadContent after creating the object itself?

As I see it you have a couple of options:

- As previously mentioned you could load all required assets for your game in the initial LoadContent method of your game loop or whenever you're loading the level/world if you have one.
- Load the required content for each object whenever it is created either by calling LoadContent() on the object in question or break the pattern and pass a ContentManager to the constructor.
- If you would like to control load/unload manually you could create your own implementation of a ContentManager by inheriting from class itself eg:

  ```
  public class MyContentManager : ContentManager
  {
      public MyContentManager(IServiceProvider serviceProvider):base(serviceProvider)
      {
      }

      public MyContentManager(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string rootDirectory) : base(serviceProvider, rootDirectory)
      {

      }

      public void Unload(string name)
      {
          // unload specific resource
          LoadedAssets.Remove(name);
      }

      public Texture2D Load(string name)
      {
          return Load<Texture2D>(name);
      }       
  }
  ```

  *If you would call contentManager.Unload() it would unload all the content but in the code sample above you can control specific resources.*

It's not uncommon to have multiple content managers, for instance you could have one which is considered "common" which loads all the content required for the game regardless of level whilst another content manager would be solely responsible for loading any level specific resources and also unloading them whenever a level changes.

To illustrate what I mean imagine following "AssetManager":

```
public static class AssetManager
{
    private static ContentManager _common;

    public static MyContentManager Level { get; private set; }

    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _common = new ContentManager(serviceProvider, "commoncontentdirectory");
        Level = new MyContentManager(serviceProvider, "levelcontentdirectory");
    }

    // A shorthand for loading an asset through the common content manager.
    public static T Load<T>(string asset)
    {
        return _common.Load<T>(asset);
    }

    // A shorthand for unloading the entire content manager for current instance.
    public static void Unload()
    {
        _common.Unload();
    }
}
```

The AssetManager could be initialized in your Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game

```
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        AssetManager.Initialize(Content.ServiceProvider);

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

And called upon whenever required using either the shorthand methods on the "AssetManager" or the instance of the level content manager through the Level property.

Comment: I can't call LoadContent after creating the object because the LoadContent function of the individual object uses the ContentManager as a parameter and I can only use this.content (the ContentManager) in the LoadContent function when the game starts and it is only called once per game.